# Is there a good way to organize chapters with Open Office Writer?

Tags: software, organization

I've found I'm writing some of 20+/- page documents that are of publishable quality. How can I organize them into chapters in order to keep them organized better than in a single document.

Comment: Can't you just open new documents for separate chapters? What software are you using?

Comment: Use bookmarks, page breaks, etc. (If your software allows this)

Comment: Use headings for chapters in a single document. OO Writer has the ability to move headers if I'm not wrong. https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Getting_Started/Using_the_Navigator

Comment: it seems to take up a ton of space